# Programatically reorder referenced entities by field

Tags: 8, entities

I have a content type Speaker that uses an Event content type as reference. The Event has a start date and time field. There can be any number of events that a speaker speaks at, when visiting the speaker page, the events are not ordered by date, they are ordered by id. How do I programmatically change this?

I am able to get the field value and sort them by date, but I am not able to set them back to the variable.

[Related Drupal API Link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21EntityReferenceFieldItemList.php/class/EntityReferenceFieldItemList/8.2.x)

```
use \Drupal\Component\Utility\SortArray;


function mytheme_preprocess_node__speaker_page(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $entity_ids = [];
  if ($node) {
    if (isset($node->field_events)) {
      $items = $node->field_events; //entity reference
      $unsorted=array();
      foreach ($items as $item) {
        $target_id = $item->target_id;
        $field_event = $item->entity;
        //creating a new unsorted array with the target id and event date, this is used for sorting
        array_push($unsorted, array('target_id' => $target_id, 'event_date' => strtotime($field_event->field_date_of_event->value)));
      }
      //sorting
      usort($unsorted, function ($a, $b) {
        return SortArray::sortByKeyInt($a, $b, 'event_date');
      });
      //sorted ids
      $new_entity_ids = array_column($unsorted, 'target_id');

      $items_new = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($new_entity_ids);
      $variables['node']->field_events = $items_new; //this doesn't work
      //$variables['node']->set($field_name)->referencedEntities(); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You still have to change the order in the render array for this to have an effect on the output.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to drop this logic into a field formatter?

Comment: That's where I would do it.

Comment: thanks @Kevin sorry I am kind of new to this, from what I understand, I will need to create a custom field formatter that sorts the referenced entities by event date and then set that field formatter for the referenced entities field in the display of the speaker content type, am I right? Wouldn't that be a longer and a time consuming way to do it? I was trying to do a quicker way since it is just a sort.

Comment: The problem is you don't really want to deal with render array manipulation here, and the moment you want to show this field anywhere else, you will have to do the code again in another place. Field Formatters are re-usable.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks @Kevin

Comment: Similar discussion about manipulating the referenced entity list in a field formatter including a code example: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294728/filter-the-list-of-entities-referenced-by-entity-reference-revisions-field

Comment: For a no-code solution you can use https://www.drupal.org/project/eva

Comment: yes, I am creating a field formatter, thanks @4k4